# Send a mail with Qt & php.exe

Tags: php, c++, qt, smtp, wamp

I have a problem with a program which I'm creating for my job. It's a C++ program which is developing with Qt.

I want to send an email, so I call php in C++:

```
QStringList l;
QString    msg(mail.c_str());
l << "C: //sql.php"; //my function which send an email
l << msg; // my email
this->_php->start("C:\\Program Files\\wamp\\bin\\php\\php5.3.8\\php.exe", l);
```

This code is working and php is not writing an error. So look my other function in php (`myemail@xxx.fr` is not my real adress :p, I have hiding it for asking my question)

```
    $headers = 'From: "xxx"<noreply@xxx.fr>' . "\n";
$headers .='Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"' . "\n";
$headers .='Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit' . "\n";

$obj = "my_object";
$msg = "<html><head></head><body>awdadwawdawd</body></html>";
if (mail("myemail@xxx.fr", $obj, $msg, $headers) == true)
    echo "ok";
else
    echo "fail";
```

So this is working because "ok" was print on my C++ program.
But this email wasn't arrived on my e-mail box.
When I try to launch the php's function in wamp (with localhost....) it's working because I received this mail. But when i try with my C++ program and `php.exe`, e-mails didn't arrived.

Someone have and idea or a suggestion to fix my problem?

Comment: why are you using php to send email?

Comment: it's a small program, already done before i'm working on it and php was already implemented for other things, so i don't want to create this with a socket in c++.... It's more easier and quick to call php to do that i think

Comment: its adding an additional dependency for your application.

Comment: "php was already implemented for other things". Dependency is already add before i began to work on it

Answer (score 0):

It seems like config problem. Check your php.ini and specially SMTP settings.

```
php -i | findstr SMTP //check SMTP server
php -i | findstr "Configuration File" //to check php.ini location
```

Comment: my php.ini (i'm on windows seven) :     [mail function]

SMTP = smtp.orange.fr
it is on the same folder that my php.exe so it's correct
smtp_port = 25

sendmail_from = noreply@xxx.fr